# $(x+1)/x = \sqrt{3}$ in form $a+b \sqrt{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The above is the problem.

I have trivially arrived at

$$
x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1}
$$

However I am unsure of how to get it into the required format.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you want to write as $a+b\sqrt 3$?

Comment: Multiply the numerator and denominator both by $\sqrt3+1$. Post the result as an answer. That is an effective way of dispelling the thoughts that you just want somebody to do your homework.

Comment: This is trivial!!!

Comment: @HassanMuhammad Don't be mean.

Answer (score 3):

$$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3-1}\times 1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3-1}\times\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{\sqrt 3+1}=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{(\sqrt 3-1)(\sqrt 3+1)}=\frac{\sqrt 3+1}{2}=\frac 12+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt 3.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1}$

Conjugating the above equation gives:

$\displaystyle x =\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}-1} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3} +1}{\sqrt{3}+1}=$
$\displaystyle  \frac{ \sqrt{3}+1}{3 - 1}$
$\displaystyle = \frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{2}$
$\displaystyle  = \sqrt{3}\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$

Thus, you get the form of $a +b\cdot\sqrt 3$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I fixed the wrong $-$ into $+$ (just a small slip).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is trivial, but here another (non trivial) way ;-)

Let $x = a + b \sqrt{3}$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$; then if $\frac{x+1}{x}=\sqrt{3}$, substitute $x$ giving $\frac{a + b \sqrt{3} +1}{a + b \sqrt{3}}=\sqrt{3}$, so $a+1+b \sqrt{3} = a \sqrt{3} + 3 b$. Therefore, $a + 1 = 3 b $ and $a =b$ (*), from which $a = b = 1/2$.

(*) in one sentence, $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$ are like two independent $\mathbb{R}$ "vectors"  over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Nice use of the fact that, when $a,b,x,y\in\mathbb Q$, we have $a+b\sqrt{3}=x+y\sqrt{3}\Leftrightarrow a=x,b=y$.

Comment: @columbus8myhw, thanks. Yes, even simple questions in maths can have deeper answers.